# Обработчик событий для кнопки в NetBeans

Tags: java

Как создаются обработчики кнопок Canсel в NetBeans на java?

Answer (score 2):

```
btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //тут твои действия, например, System.exit(0);
    }
});
```